# Differentiate between ELFves and scripts quickly

Tags: files, scripting, executable, elf

How do I use `file` to differentiate between ELFves and scripts as quickly as possible?

I don't need any further details, just *ELF*, *script* (*/plaintext*), or *other/error*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it's just between ELF and script, you may not need `file` at all. With `bash`:

```
IFS= LC_ALL=C read -rn4 -d '' x < file
case $x in
  ($'\x7fELF') echo ELF;;
  ("#!"*) echo script;;
  (*) echo other;;
esac
```

(`-d ''` (to use NUL character as delimiter) is to work around the fact that `bash`'s `read` otherwise just ignores the NUL bytes in the input).

See also:

- [Searching for 32-bit ELF file](/a/272184)
- [Fastest way to determine if shebang is present](/a/406939)

Answer (score 2):

Create a custom [magic(5)](http://linux.die.net/man/5/magic) file that contains only the tests you need.

The stock `elf` test can be fetched from https://github.com/file/file/blob/master/magic/Magdir/elf , and then cut down even further. `text` is built-in, so you don't need to include it.

To avoid the parsing it each time, put it in its own directory and compile it to `mgc`:

```
file -C -m dir
```

This will output `dir.mgc`.  (Specifying `-m dir/` will instead output `.mgc`.)  Then it will be used by subsequent runs:

```
file -m dir
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I can exclude the following tests to speed it up:

```
encoding tokens cdf compress elf tar
```

(Tests are excluded with `-e $test_name`).

It looks like I need the `ascii` and the `soft` test.